# How can I install playerctl?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I want to install playerctl and I downloaded it from GitHub, since apt doesn't have it. Then I need a gobject-2.0, which cannot be installed by apt, because it uses regexes and because of that dependencies aren't met.

So to install gobject2.0 I downloaded glib-master which also can't install, it says, because I don't have package `mount`. That makes no sense; I certainly have it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want playerctl, I would suggest you download the `.deb`-files and install them rather than compiling yourself:

- [libplayerctl](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libplayerctl2) (dependency of playerctl)
- [playerctl](https://packages.debian.org/buster/playerctl)

Here's what I did on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS:

```
wget http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/playerctl/libplayerctl2_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/playerctl/playerctl_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libplayerctl2_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb playerctl_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```

For this to work all other dependencies must be met, of course. They were in my case.

Comment: The link to package libplayerctl is broken.

Comment: The linked libplayerctl package was removed from Buster and replaced by libplayerctl2 -- link updated.

Answer (score 4):

In [Ubuntu 20.04 and onwards](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=playerctl), playerctl is available via apt in the `universe` repository:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install playerctl
```